# Phonegap Navigator Notification Confirmback not working in sequence

Tags: cordova, notifications

The app has a button to delete a dblog. When the user clicks on the button, I ask for a confirmation and then go ahead and delete.

I am using navigator.notification.confirm to ask the user

Here is my code -

```
function deleteLog()
{

    navigator.notification.confirm(
    "Are you sure you want delete?",
    function(buttonIndex){
        if(buttonIndex==1)
        {
            console.log("User has cancelled");
            return;
        }
    },
    "Confirmation",
    "Cancel, Delete");

    console.log("User has confirmed Delete");


}
```

However, even before the user clicks on Cancel or Delete, I get "User has confirmed" message. I tried adding a else statement above, and still no luck.

What could be wrong?

EDIT:
Some more information -

The sequence I like is Single Thread === Press Delete -> Ask for Confirmation -> User Pressed Delete -> Delete dbLog.

What is happening Press Delete --> Thread One == Ask for Confirmation
Thread Two (after Press Delete) --> Deleting DB Log

Comment: The return exit from anonymous function not from deleteLog function so console.log("User has confirmed Delete"); was always shown.

Answer (score 2):

By putting there console.log("User has confirmed Delete"), out of the callback, you are basically telling the program to run the console.log whatever the user presses.

I would take the confirmation function out for better usability and write it like this:

```
function deleteLog() {
    navigator.notification.confirm(
        'Are you sure you want delete?', // message
        onConfirm,                       // callback to invoke with index of button
        'Confirmation',                  // title
        'Cancel,Delete'                  // buttonLabels
    );
}

//on button press, the onConfirm function is called
function onConfirm(button) {
    //console.log('You selected button ' + button);
    if(button == 1){
        //pressed "cancel"
        console.log("User has cancelled");
    }
    else if(button == 2){
        //pressed "delete"
        console.log("User has confirmed Delete");
    }
}
```

This works.

Comment: See above. I have said it doesn't work using else statement as well. I still copy-pasted the code, and it is not working.

Comment: the problem in your code is the positioning of "console.log("User has confirmed Delete")"

Did you try and see if both buttons don't work with my code or maybe just one? I am using basically the same code piece and it works perfectly for me.

Comment: Yes. I copy n pasted your code. It does not work. Can you share the working jsfiddle if possible?

Comment: I would but you can't jsfiddle phonegap methods (like navigator.notification.confirm) because it would need the specific libraries. What PG version are you running? If you look at PG docs their notification example is very similar to what I wrote. If you copied n pasted my code make sure you are calling it correctly from your html. I run it again and it works. What exactly is not working in my code in your app?

Comment: I am using PG2.4. I have updated the original question with more info. I need the entire sequence to run sequentially, but it happens parallely. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: gcatalfamo's answer is the correct one; the code needs to be inside the callback (unlike browser js). However I have observed that console.log seems not to work in notification callbacks (Cordova 2.4.0) so I suggest using gcatalfamos code then changing all console.logs to alerts.